# Embeded Flash content do not play on Timeline

Tags: flash, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I've a Flash application embed in a html page and I wan't to play it on timeline when an user share this page. I've read the doc (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) and added the good og meta but when I share a page, the Flash application can be used directly on Timeline, in fact, it's a link to the web page.

It's my header :

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Albumblog" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="My Description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mydomain.com/myimage.png" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.mydomain.com/module/viewer/index.swf?book_id=1&book_token=2&token=3&gateway_url=http://www.mydomain.com/ws.php/amfgateway/service&src=abg&production_mode=true" /> 
<meta property="og:video:height" content="386" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width" content="393" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

I've another problem with the facebook url sharer (sharer.php), the get parameter "t" is not working. Just test this : https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sadtrombone.com%2F&t=HELLOWORLD and it's not working. The url is encoded and the title is "normal" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the video to play in the timeline, remove the `og:video` tags from the page. Instead, let the page pick up the `og:image` when someone shares your page. The user will then have to click on the image or link and be redirected to your site where they can view the video.

The `t=...` parameter has been long ignored by the Facebook Sharing script. You have to use `og:title` on your page to customise the title instead.